# model loading with assimp - boost not necessary?

Tags: c++, opengl, boost, assimp

[In chapter for model loading with learnopenGL using Assimp library](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Assimp) there used to be a notice(which is still available in it's offline transcript) saying:

> If you want Assimp to use multi-threading for faster performance you could compile Assimp with Boost. You can find the full installation instruction at their installation page.

But, the link [pointed to is dead](https://assimp.org/lib_html/install.html). And I found a [thread](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/409) where a user was trying to replace `Boost` features with `C++11`. And I thought if using `Boost` library was no longer necessary ? Please tell me if Boost is required or not anymore and does `Assimp` do multithreading by default now or it is using `C++11` features for it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they don't list boost ass a requirement, that probably means it's not a requirement. They should not be required to list absence of requirements. [Changelog doesn't explicitly mention it](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases)

Trawling the git commits:

#### [Dox: remove parts about boost support - already replaced by c++11](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/commit/4b4f18fb3111bf0368f489fe339ae68a7c72f228)

```
commit 4b4f18fb3111bf0368f489fe339ae68a7c72f228
Author: Kim Kulling <kim.kulling@googlemail.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 19 21:46:02 2018 +0100
```

#### [C++11-Support: remove boost.](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/commit/6b243230b29d14e778563f2855164f172a00ca77)

```
commit 6b243230b29d14e778563f2855164f172a00ca77
Author: Kim Kulling <kim.kulling@googlemail.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 7 21:31:04 2016 +0200
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this website [Asset-Importer-Lib](https://assimp-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)to get the latest documentation. Our doxygen-doc is outdated and we moved to swing to create our documentation.